# Mixed Partials and Continuity

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose the mixed partials of some function $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ give $-1$ and $1$ at the origin. Is that enough to conclude that the partials are discontinuous? Or is that enough to conclude that $f$ is not $C^2$ because if $f$ was $C^2$ then the mixed partials would be equal? Then if the partials are equal could we conclude that they are continuous on the domain?

Comment: If $f$ is $p$-times differentiable (with or without continuity), then the order in which the $p$th partial derivatives is taken does not matter. In particular, if $f$ is twice differentiable, $\partial_{x,y} f = \partial_{y,x} f.$

Comment: I thought this result only applied if $f$ is $C^p$?

Comment: Be careful here. Saying $f$ is twice differentiable is much stronger than saying its second-order partial derivatives exist.

Comment: Sorry, I am out of the loop could you elaborate Ted? I understand that partials existing does not imply differentiablity, but who were you addressing when you made your comment?

Comment: $C^p \implies p \text{ times differentiable} \implies \text{ there exists partials of }p\text{th order}.$ The previous implications cannot be reverted. Observe however that $$C^p \iff \text{ there exists partials of }p\text{th order and they all are continuous.}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your deductions are correct, for if the mixed partials are continuous, then they would be equal. Also, if the function was twice continuously differentiable, then the mixed partials would necessarily be continuous, and thus equal; but they are not.

Comment: Okay I see. I do have a followup question. Suppose the partials are discontinuous at a point. This is NOT sufficient to show that the function $f$ is not differentiable. We have only shown that the function is not $C^r$ correct?

Comment: @JamesEade You would be right if you were talking about first partials. Yes, that these are discontinuous doesn't mean the function is not differentiable; what it means is that the derivative is not continuous.

Comment: Ah okay, and so the same applies for all derivatives. If the mixed partials are not equal then we have shown that $f$ is not $C^2$, correct?

Comment: @JamesEade Yes, you would have shown that.